# Conditionals within captions

Tags: captions, conditionals

I have defined a conditional using the `ifthen` package as:

```
\newcommand{\Switch}[1] { \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{Test1}{Test2} }
```

Running this command works without problem. However, if I try to place it within a Figure Caption, it produces an error (i.e., `\Switch{1}` and `\caption{Example text}` work fine, but `\caption{\Switch{1}}` does not).

Is this expected behavior? How do I work around it to produce a conditional caption?

Answer (score 6):

The `\ifthenelse` command appears to be fragile? `\caption{\protect\Switch{1}}` works.

Answer (score 3):

As a modern alternative, you can use the commands from the `etoolbox` package:

```
\newcommand*{\Switch}[1]{\ifnumequal{#1}{1}{Test1}{Test2}}
```

Or the `xparse` package:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \Switch { m } {
  \int_compare:nNnTF { #1 } = { \c_one } {
    Test1
  } {
    Test2
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: You don't like `\int_compare:nTF { #1=1 }`? No need for using the constant here (in fact, we shouldn't be promoting their use much, really).

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions work, just adding this one for completeness. It also has the advantage of not needing `\protect`.

Declare your command as robust with:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Switch}[1] { \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{Test1}{Test2} }
```

You can now use `\caption{\Switch{1}}` just fine.

See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61503/newcommand-vs-declarerobustcommand) for details about the difference between `\newcommand` and `\DeclareRobustCommand`.