# How can I define a macro, so that is does not have to be preceded by \protect in headings, captions etc.?

Tags: macros, errors

I tried to define a macro myself, which outputs different strings according to the input variable (like select-case  statements in other programming languages).

## The problem:

If I use the code in headings, captions, etc., I get error messages and no pdf, unless I put a `\protect` before the macro (see example below).

I'd like to avoid that - can I redefine the macro to make it "robust" also in such environments?

### Example file

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\ed}[1]{% source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64131/4009, needs package xstring
\textcolor{magenta}{
\,\bfseries\itshape\IfStrEqCase{#1}{{1}{A}
    {8}{B}
    {5}{C}
{3}{D}
{7}{E}
{11}{F}
{14}{G}
{16}{H}
{19}{J}}
    [??]
}} 

\listfiles

\begin{document}


1 \ed{1}

2 \ed{2}

3 \ed{3}

4 \ed{4} 

test

\section{in headings it does not work like \ed{11}, at leat in the main document}



\end{document}
```

Comment: `\DeclareRobustCommand` perhaps? ;-)

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61503/newcommand-vs-declarerobustcommand for a discussion on `\newcommand` vs. `\DeclareRobustCommand`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\DeclareRobustCommand` can be used for such cases, however, there are expansion issues (i.e. it's not expandible).

The code uses the original version and a `\DeclareRobustCommand` version.

In addition one could use

- `\newrobustcmd` from `etoolbox` package
- `\NewDocumentCommand` from `xparse` package

---

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\ed}[1]{% source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64131/4009, needs package xstring
\textcolor{magenta}{
\,\bfseries\itshape\IfStrEqCase{#1}{{1}{A}
    {8}{B}
    {5}{C}
{3}{D}
{7}{E}
{11}{F}
{14}{G}
{16}{H}
{19}{J}}
    [??]
}} 

\newrobustcmd{\edetoolbox}[1]{% source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64131/4009, needs package xstring
\textcolor{magenta}{
\,\bfseries\itshape\IfStrEqCase{#1}{{1}{A}
    {8}{B}
    {5}{C}
{3}{D}
{7}{E}
{11}{F}
{14}{G}
{16}{H}
{19}{J}}
    [??]
}} 


\NewDocumentCommand{\edxparse}{m}{% source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64131/4009, needs package xstring
\textcolor{magenta}{
\,\bfseries\itshape\IfStrEqCase{#1}{{1}{A}
    {8}{B}
    {5}{C}
{3}{D}
{7}{E}
{11}{F}
{14}{G}
{16}{H}
{19}{J}}
    [??]
}} 




\DeclareRobustCommand{\edother}[1]{% source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64131/4009, needs package xstring
\textcolor{magenta}{
\,\bfseries\itshape\IfStrEqCase{#1}{{1}{A}
    {8}{B}
    {5}{C}
{3}{D}
{7}{E}
{11}{F}
{14}{G}
{16}{H}
{19}{J}}
    [??]
}} 


\listfiles

\begin{document}


1 \ed{1}

2 \ed{2}

3 \ed{3}

4 \ed{4} 

test

\section{in headings it does not work like \protect\ed{11}, at leat in the main document}

\section{in headings it does not work like \edother{11}, at leat in the main document}

\section{in headings it does not work like \edetoolbox{11}, at leat in the main document}

\section{in headings it does not work like \edxparse{11}, at leat in the main document}



\end{document}
```

Comment: There's also `\robustify` from `etoolbox`.

Comment: @Manuel: I know, but I never used it so far. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When we are using plain TeX then we have two ways how to protect the macro. First one is possible by eTeX extension (commonly used). Instead of `\def\macro` we must say

```
\protected\def\macro
```

This technique is possible in LaTeX too.

The second more comfortable way is available when OPmac macro package is used. We can say

```
\addprotect\macro
```

which registers the control sequence `\macro` as protected. We needn't to change the definition of the `\macro` itself. The `\addprotect` declaration from OPmac works in classical TeX and we can use it before definition of the macro or after it. This doesn't matter.