# TikZ: non-active semi-colon

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions

I have used TikZ to define an extensible arrow interrupted by symbols similar to `\xrightarrow`.

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\oprightarrow}[1]{%
\mathbin{%
\tikz[baseline=-3pt]{%
\node[text depth=0,inner sep=1.5pt] (n) {\ensuremath{\scriptstyle #1}};%
\draw (n.west) -- +(-.7em,0);%
\draw[->] (n.east) -- +(.7em,0);%
}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
   \caption{$P\oprightarrow{\varphi}Q$}
\end{figure}

$P\oprightarrow{\varphi} Q$

\end{document}
```

While this works fine in normal situations, I encounter an error while using it in a figure's caption:

```
./test_mwe.tex:16: Undefined control sequence.
\tikz@deactivatthings ->\def ;
                          {\tikz@nonactivesemicolon }\def :{\tikz@nonact...
l.16    \caption{$P\oprightarrow{\varphi}Q$}

./test_mwe.tex:16: Undefined control sequence.
\tikz@deactivatthings ...onactivesemicolon }\def :
                                              {\tikz@nonactivecolon }\de...
l.16    \caption{$P\oprightarrow{\varphi}Q$}

./test_mwe.tex:16: Undefined control sequence.
\tikz@deactivatthings ...kz@nonactivecolon }\def |
                                              {\tikz@nonactivebar }\def ...
l.16    \caption{$P\oprightarrow{\varphi}Q$}

./test_mwe.tex:16: Undefined control sequence.
\tikz@deactivatthings ...tikz@nonactivebar }\def !
                                              {\tikz@nonactiveexlmark }
l.16    \caption{$P\oprightarrow{\varphi}Q$}
```

I know that there can be trouble mixing babel and tikz, e.g. with french language making the colon and semi-colon become active characters. But this seems to be something different.

FWIW, the caption is typeset correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `\DeclareRobustCommand{\oprightarrow}[1]{...}`

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61503/newcommand-vs-declarerobustcommand

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `\tikz[...]{...}` command is essentially equivalent to `\begin{tikzpicture}[...]...\end{tikzpicture}` and `\begin` is a *fragile* command. This makes also your `\oprightarrow` command into a fragile command that needs `\protect` in front of it when it appears in a moving argument, such as a caption text or a sectional title.

Thus

```
\caption{$P\protect\oprightarrow{\varphi}Q$}
```

would solve the issue, but it's better if you solve it completely by doing `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\oprightarrow}[1]{%
  \mathrel{%
    \tikz[baseline=-3pt]{%
      \node[text depth=0,inner sep=1.5pt] (n) {$\scriptstyle #1$};%
      \draw (n.west) -- +(-.7em,0);%
      \draw[->] (n.east) -- +(.7em,0);%
    }%
  }%
}
```

Note that an arrow should be a relation symbol (hence `\mathrel`) and that `\ensuremath` is just making TeX do more work for nothing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\oprightarrow}[1]{%
  \mathrel{%
    \tikz[baseline=-3pt]{%
      \node[text depth=0,inner sep=1.5pt] (n) {$\scriptstyle #1$};%
      \draw (n.west) -- +(-.7em,0);%
      \draw[->] (n.east) -- +(.7em,0);%
    }%
  }%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
   \caption{$P\oprightarrow{\varphi}Q$}
\end{figure}

$P\oprightarrow{\varphi} Q$

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can check that this works also with `babel-french`.

On the other hand, you can solve the same problem without TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\oprightarrow}[1]{%
  \mathrel{-}
  \mathrel{\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptstyle\,\mathstrut#1\,$}}}
  \rightarrow
}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
   \caption{$P\oprightarrow{\varphi}Q$}
\end{figure}

$P\oprightarrow{\varphi} Q$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, not only for solving the main problem, but also for the remarks on the macro itself, especially the `\mathrel` (I actually hesitated) and the useless use of `\ensuremath`.

Comment: Just read about your `\ensuremath`-only-when-really-needed campaign :)

Comment: @PhilippImhof I added a different solution that has the advantage of using the standard arrow.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you for that solution. It is indeed much more elegant than mine.