# Circled text with tikz Black background and white text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, backgrounds

Given this simple scenario:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\encircle[1]{%
\tikz[baseline=(X.base)] 
   \node (X) [draw, shape=circle, inner sep=0] {\strut #1};}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\encircle{A}
\end{document}
```

The output is this:
[image]

How do I change it so that the circle has a black background and the color of the text inside the circle is white (basically, reversing the colors) ?

Answer (score 9):

Use the `fill` key to set the background colour and the `text` key to set the text colour; in your application this means `fill=black, text=white`.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\encircle[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(X.base)] 
    \node (X) [draw, shape=circle, inner sep=0, fill=black, text=white] {\strut #1};%
}
\begin{document}
\encircle{A}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To deal with any errors do:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\encircle[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=circle,fill,inner sep=2pt] (char) {\textcolor{white}{#1}}}}
```

[TikZ: non-active semi-colon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258995/tikz-non-active-semi-colon)